# Contiki OS: rom partition

Tags: rom, contiki

I am trying to compile a project on Contiki but I have this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.5.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: dora_main.sky section `.data' will not fit in region `rom'
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.5.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: section .vectors loaded at [0000ffe0,0000ffff] overlaps section .data loaded at [0000ff0c,00010131]
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.5.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: region `rom' overflowed by 338 bytes
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Someone told me that I have to reduce the ROM partition. Is it true? How could I do that?

Comment: Is your Contiki project big?

Answer (score 2):

Your project is simply to big for the MSP430s memory.

Your options basically are to either trim the binary or if you are lucky you have to update your compiler to use all of the devices memory

## 1. Trimming the binary

- by checking if you compile with `-0s`
- by removing debug output and other strings from the binary
- by removing Contiki Apps you might not need

## 2. Use MSP430X

If you have a MSP430 with more than 32kByte (e.g. [MSP430F5335](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430f5335)) of flash you can change the memory model with the following flags in your makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -mmemory-model=large \
     -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections \
     -mcode-region=far -mdata-region=far
LDFLAGS += -mmemory-model=large \
     -Wl,-gc-sections \
     -mcode-region=far -mdata-region=far
```

This will move your code and data past the 16 bit boundary to use all the memory the device supports. See [MSP430X](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/MSP430X) section of the Contiki Wiki for more information on how to do this.